# Show vote buttons for historical notice locked posts

Tags: feature-request, voting, design, historical-lock

On the UX Stack Exchange, recently there was a [discussion about the vote buttons on Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53986/why-are-vote-buttons-on-stack-exchange-shown-when-they-cant-be-used).

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon), the voting buttons are not there, unlike other posts:

> [image: Inconsistency of the UX]

[On this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225784/why-vote-buttons-hidden-in-locked-questions), it says that because nobody can vote, it doesn't show it. The accidental discovery could show a message like `You can't vote on locked posts`, kind of like the 'you need 15 rep', or 'you can't vote on your own posts' messages. While the rationale is 'it's a global state', it's inconsistent with the rest of the site.

Can we please put the vote arrows back in those posts, same way we have in other locked posts?

Comment: @Mat This was more of a feature request to change it, while the other one is just a discussion.

Comment: @justcool393 no this is not a feature request. "why isn't the buttons shown when the post is locked?" is a support question. If you'll edit the question into feature request (e.g. Show vote buttons in locked posted) I will retract my close vote.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Nope. You are still asking a question, not suggesting any new feature (feature request should be "Please do X", not "Why isn't it X?". Want me to try and edit it into proper request?

Comment: The other question explains why they are hidden...

Comment: This seems more like a discussion to me. You didn't convince us that it should be there, and the answer to your question is in the post you linked.please read more here:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info

Answer (score 6):

The lack of vote buttons is a signal that the page you are looking at is not "normal".

[Historical posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) are no longer part of the standard Q&A post system, and as such, should not feature the same UI dress as you would see of questions that can be edited, closed and/or deleted.

They are abominations, anomalies and aberrant.

Comment: Not to mention abhorrent, atypical and apathetic.